# Logging ffmpeg console information

Tags: logging, windows-7, ffmpeg

I have just started using ffmpeg for splitting up a video into images. What I would like to know if it is possible to have the console output information saved out into a log file. I've tried the "-v 10" argument and I've tried the "-loglevel" argument. I've seen on another SO post to use the

`ffmpeg -i myinput.avi {a-bunch-of-important-params} out.flv 2> /path/to/out.txt`

but I get errors stating that it doesn't know what the txt format is. I am running this on a Windows 7 SP1 machine. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: could you paste the exact error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters you provided seems to be correct, but the issue may be in your `/path/to/out.txt` parameter. In case if it contains a space symbol you'll probably get this error:

`Unable to find a suitable output format for '\out.txt'`

To make it work just put it in double quotes:

```
ffmpeg -i myinput.avi {a-bunch-of-important-params} out.flv 2> "/path/to/out.txt"
```